# vaadin-combo-box / vaadin-combo-box-overlay change background color / Polymer API

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, vaadin

I'm trying to override the background color present in `vaadin-combo-box-overlay` element.

Here is the css that I want to override, more specifically the background property, source taken from (https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/blob/master/vaadin-combo-box-overlay.html)

```
:host {
      position: absolute;
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
  .......
    }
```

So I've tried something like:

```
 :root ::content vaadin-combo-box-overlay.vaadin-combo-box-overlay {
                            background: red !important;
                            background-color: red !important;
 }
```

Also I've tried with `:host` but I guess it should be used `:root` because I use this dropdown in a dialog, and the overlay component doesn't seem to be a child of the dialog. I've tried different combinatons as the one mentioned above without any success.

Also I'm wondering why the background is not parameterized as the text color is:

```
 #selector .item {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 13px 16px;
      color: var(--primary-text-color);
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

Specifying a different value for `--primary-text-color` I'm able to change the text color..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Patrick !!

I wasn't thinking about to do try it this way.

Here's what I did, a hacky solution though.

```
ready : function(){
                var combo = this.$$('#comboid');
                combo.addEventListener('vaadin-dropdown-opened'', function() {
                    var overlay = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#overlay');
                    overlay.style.backgroundColor = primaryBackground;
                });
            },
```

I only have access to the overlay when the combo is expanded, so in the value change listener the combo would be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with javascript like that.

```
    ready: function() {
      var domElem=Polymer.dom(this).node.$.YOUR-VAADIN-ELEMENT-ID.$.overlay.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
```

OR

```
ready: function() {
          var css = '#selector .item { background-color:red; }';
          var style = document.createElement('style');
              style.type = 'text/css';
              style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
          Polymer.dom(this).node.$.tourSelector.$.overlay.$.selector.appendChild(style);
        }
```

Would like to have a working CSS selector, but i cant set breakpoints in CSS to find out the right selectors!

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`dom-module`** for styling vaading parts see example below:

```
<dom-module id="combo-box-overlay-styles" theme-for="vaadin-combo-box-overlay">
    <template>
        <style>
            [part~="content"] {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Read more here https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki

Comment: Beware, the documentation is horrible so you're going to have to piece together answers from all over the place in it, along with random stackoverflow answers.

Comment: @electrovir that's unfortunately true